# How can I have all cores participate in parallelization with Async?

Tags: asynchronous, parallel-processing, f#

The following functions parallelize the processing of a list by first decomposing a list into large chunks and then processing each chunk.

```
let chunkList chunkSize (xs : list<'T>) = 
    query {
        for idx in 0..(xs.Length - 1) do
        groupBy (idx / chunkSize) into g
        select (g |> Seq.map (fun idx -> xs.[idx]))
    }
let par (foo: 'T -> 'S) (xs: list<'T>) = 
    xs
    |> List.map (fun x -> async { return foo x })
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> Array.toList

let parChunks chunkSize (f: 'T -> 'S) (xs: list<'T>) =
    chunkList chunkSize xs |> Seq.map List.ofSeq |> List.ofSeq
    |> par (List.map f)
    |> List.concat
```

This function was used to test `parChunks`:

```
let g i = [1..1000000] |> List.map (fun x -> sqrt (float (1000 * x + 1))) |> List.head
```

Running the standard `List.Seq` and `parChunk`` with a chunk size equal to 1/2 the list size there was a performance gain:

> List.map g [1..100];;
>   // Real: 00:00:28.979, CPU: 00:00:29.562
>
> parChunks 50 g [1..100];;
>   // Real: 00:00:23.027, CPU: 00:00:24.687

However, with a chunk size equal to 1/4 the size of the list the performance was almost the same. I did not expect this since my processor (`Intel 6700HQ`) has four cores.

> parChunks 25 g [1..100];;
>   // Real: 00:00:21.695, CPU: 00:00:24.437

Looking at the `Performance` app in `Task Manager` one sees that the four cores are never used.

Is there a way to make all four cores participate in this computation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating this problem.

The primary use of `async` workflows is not for CPU-bound work, it's for IO-bound work to avoid blocking threads while awaiting results that will arrive with some latency.

Although you can parallelise CPU-bound work using `async`, doing so is suboptimal.

What you want can be far more easily achieved by using the `Array.Parallel` module on `Array`s rather than `List`s.

```
let g i = 
    [|1..1000000|] 
    |> Array.Parallel.map (fun x -> sqrt (float (1000 * x + 1))) 
    |> Array.head
```

No need to write your own chunking and merging code, that's all handled for you and, by my measurements, it's much much faster.

Comment: Thanks! I tested your suggestion of `Array.Parallel.map`, `PSeq.map` and my own `parChunks` adapted to use `Array.Parallel.map`, all with another function that included calculating `sin(x)`. `chunkSizes` was extremely slow (not clear why), `PSeq.map` was much faster than `Seq.map`, and the winner was `Array.Parallel.map`, roughly 15% faster than `PSeq.map`. With this new test function `Array.Parallel.map` brings CPU utilization to about 80%, which is close to ideal. Still, I miss some control over CPU utilization or number of cores used.

Answer (score 3):

In F#, `async` workflows run using [the .Net `ThreadPool` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx), which has `GetMinThreads` and `GetMaxThreads` methods. They use two `out` parameters to return the minimum or maximum number of threads that the thread pool is allowed to use, but in F# that gets converted to a function returning a tuple:

```
F# Interactive for F# 4.1
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License

For help type #help;;

> open System.Threading ;;
> ThreadPool.GetMinThreads() ;;
val it : int * int = (4, 4)

> ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads() ;;
val it : int * int = (400, 200)
```

The two numbers are for "worker" threads and "asynchronous I/O" threads, respectively. My CPU has four cores, so the minimum number of both kinds of threads in the pool is 4. I don't know for certain that this is your problem, but try running `ThreadPool.GetMinThreads()` on your system and make sure that it's 4. If it's 2 for some reason, that could explain why you're not getting better performance.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/26041852/2314532 for an explanation of another possible performance problem with using `async` workflows for parallel processing. That could also be what's happening here.

Finally, there's one more thing I want to mention. As it currently stands, I'm genuinely surprised that you're getting any benefit out of your parallelism. That's because there's a cost to dividing up the list and concatenating it again. Since the F# list type is a singly-linked list, that cost is O(N), and those steps (divide and reassemble) cannot be parallelized.

The answer to that problem is to use a different data structure, like an [RRB Tree](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/169879/files/RMTrees.pdf), for any list of items that you plan to process in parallel: it's designed to be split and concatenated efficiently (effectively O(1) splits and joins, though the constant factor in joins is rather large). Unfortunately, there's currently no implementation of RRB trees in F#. I'm currently working on one, and estimate it may be ready in another month or so. You can subscribe to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Collections/issues/72) if you want to find out when I've released the code I've been working on.

Comment: The result of running `ThreadPool.GetMinThreads()` is (8,8) in my system. My example was designed to minimize the impact of splitting and concatenating the list, as the list is divided into only a few chunks (2 or 4) and the function being called is expensive. This would be the typical case for the kind of problems I am interested in. Running similar code with a light function and a list split into many chunks one gets indeed longer execution times. I wanted to split the list into the number of cores hoping that all cores would then be used. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Good answers here but I will add some comments when it comes to performance and parallelism.

For performance in general, we like to avoid dynamic allocations because we don't want to waste precious cycles allocating objects (quite fast in .NET, slow in C/C++) or collecting them (quite slow).

We also like to minimize the memory footprint of objects and make sure they lay sequentially in memory (Arrays are our friends here) in order to make as efficient use of the CPU cache and prefetcher as possible. A cache miss might cost several hundred cycles.

I think it is important to always compare against a trivial, sequential yet efficiently implemented loop in order to have some sanity check of the parallel performance. Otherwise we might trick ourselves into thinking our parallel masterpiece is doing well when in reality it's outclassed by a simple loop.

Also, varying the size of the input data because of caching issues but also because there is overhead from starting up a parallel computation.

With that said, I have prepared different versions of the following code:

```
module SequentialFold =
  let compute (vs : float []) : float =
    vs |> Array.fold (fun s v -> s + sqrt (1000. * v + 1.)) 0.
```

then I compare the performance of the different versions in order to see which does the best on varying sized in terms of performance and GC pressure.

The performance test is done in such a way that the total amount of work is always the same regardless of input size in order to make times comparable.

Here is the code:

```
open System
open System.Threading.Tasks

let clock =
  let sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch ()
  sw.Start ()
  fun () -> sw.ElapsedMilliseconds

let timeIt n a = 
  let r                 = a ()  // Warm-up

  GC.Collect (2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true)

  let inline cc g       = GC.CollectionCount g
  let bcc0, bcc1, bcc2  = cc 0, cc 1, cc 2
  let before            = clock ()

  for i = 1 to n do
    a () |> ignore

  let after             = clock ()
  let acc0, acc1, acc2  = cc 0, cc 1, cc 2

  after - before, acc0 - bcc0, acc1 - bcc1, acc2 - bcc2, r

// compute implemented using tail recursion
module TailRecursion =
  let compute (vs : float []) : float =
    let rec loop s i =
      if i < vs.Length then
        let v = vs.[i]
        loop (s + sqrt (1000. * v + 1.)) (i + 1)
      else
        s
    loop 0. 0

// compute implemented using Array.fold
module SequentialFold =
  let compute (vs : float []) : float =
    vs |> Array.fold (fun s v -> s + sqrt (1000. * v + 1.)) 0. 

// compute implemented using Array.map + Array.fold
module SequentialArray =
  let compute (vs : float []) : float =
    vs |> Array.map (fun v -> sqrt (1000. * v + 1.)) |> Array.fold (+) 0. 

// compute implemented using Array.Parallel.map + Array.fold
module ParallelArray =
  let compute (vs : float []) : float =
    vs |> Array.Parallel.map (fun v -> sqrt (1000. * v + 1.)) |> Array.fold (+) 0. 

// compute implemented using Parallel.For
module ParallelFor =
  let compute (vs : float []) : float =
    let lockObj         = obj ()
    let mutable sum     = 0.
    let options         = ParallelOptions()
    let init ()         = 0.
    let body i pls s    =
      let v = i |> float
      s + sqrt (1000. * v + 1.)
    let localFinally ls =
      lock lockObj <| fun () -> sum <- sum + ls
    let pls = Parallel.For  (                                             0
                            ,                                             vs.Length
                            ,                                             options
                            , Func<float>                                 init          
                            , Func<int, ParallelLoopState, float, float>  body          
                            , Action<float>                               localFinally  
                            )
    sum

// compute implemented using Parallel.For with batches of size 100
module ParallelForBatched =
  let compute (vs : float []) : float =
    let inner           = 100
    let outer           = vs.Length / inner + (if vs.Length % inner = 0 then 0 else 1)
    let lockObj         = obj ()
    let mutable sum     = 0.
    let options         = ParallelOptions()
    let init ()         = 0.
    let rec loop e s i  =
      if i < e then
        let v = vs.[i]
        loop e (s + sqrt (1000. * v + 1.)) (i + 1)
      else
        s
    let body i pls s    =
      let b = i * inner
      let e = b + inner |> min vs.Length
      loop e s b
    let localFinally ls =
      lock lockObj <| fun () -> sum <- sum + ls
    let pls = Parallel.For  (                                             0
                            ,                                             outer
                            ,                                             options
                            , Func<float>                                 init          
                            , Func<int, ParallelLoopState, float, float>  body          
                            , Action<float>                               localFinally  
                            )
    sum

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  let count   = 100000000
  let outers  =
    [|
      //10000000
      100000
      1000
      10
    |]

  for outer in outers do
    let inner     = count / outer
    let vs        = Array.init inner float
    let testCases = 
      [|
        "TailRecursion"         , fun ()  -> TailRecursion.compute    vs 
        "Fold.Sequential"       , fun ()  -> SequentialFold.compute   vs
        "Array.Sequential"      , fun ()  -> SequentialArray.compute  vs
        "Array.Parallel"    , fun ()  -> ParallelArray.compute    vs
        "Parallel.For"          , fun ()  -> ParallelFor.compute      vs
        "Parallel.For.Batched"  , fun ()  -> ParallelForBatched.compute      vs
      |]
    printfn "Using outer = %A, inner = %A, total is: %A" outer inner count
    for nm, a in testCases do
      printfn "  Running test case: %A" nm
      let tm, cc0, cc1, cc2, r = timeIt outer a
      printfn "   it took %A ms with GC collects (%A, %A, %A), result is: %A" tm cc0 cc1 cc2 r
  0
```

And here are the results (Intel I5, 4 cores):

```
Using outer = 100000, inner = 1000, total is: 100000000
  Running test case: "TailRecursion"
   it took 389L ms with GC collects (0, 0, 0), result is: 666162.111
  Running test case: "Fold.Sequential"
   it took 388L ms with GC collects (0, 0, 0), result is: 666162.111
  Running test case: "Array.Sequential"
   it took 628L ms with GC collects (255, 0, 0), result is: 666162.111
  Running test case: "Array.Parallel"
   it took 993L ms with GC collects (306, 2, 0), result is: 666162.111
  Running test case: "Parallel.For"
   it took 711L ms with GC collects (54, 2, 0), result is: 666162.111
  Running test case: "Parallel.For.Batched"
   it took 490L ms with GC collects (52, 2, 0), result is: 666162.111
Using outer = 1000, inner = 100000, total is: 100000000
  Running test case: "TailRecursion"
   it took 389L ms with GC collects (0, 0, 0), result is: 666661671.1
  Running test case: "Fold.Sequential"
   it took 388L ms with GC collects (0, 0, 0), result is: 666661671.1
  Running test case: "Array.Sequential"
   it took 738L ms with GC collects (249, 249, 249), result is: 666661671.1
  Running test case: "Array.Parallel"
   it took 565L ms with GC collects (249, 249, 249), result is: 666661671.1
  Running test case: "Parallel.For"
   it took 157L ms with GC collects (0, 0, 0), result is: 666661671.1
  Running test case: "Parallel.For.Batched"
   it took 110L ms with GC collects (0, 0, 0), result is: 666661671.1
Using outer = 10, inner = 10000000, total is: 100000000
  Running test case: "TailRecursion"
   it took 387L ms with GC collects (0, 0, 0), result is: 6.666666168e+11
  Running test case: "Fold.Sequential"
   it took 390L ms with GC collects (0, 0, 0), result is: 6.666666168e+11
  Running test case: "Array.Sequential"
   it took 811L ms with GC collects (3, 3, 3), result is: 6.666666168e+11
  Running test case: "Array.Parallel"
   it took 567L ms with GC collects (4, 4, 4), result is: 6.666666168e+11
  Running test case: "Parallel.For"
   it took 151L ms with GC collects (0, 0, 0), result is: 6.666666168e+11
  Running test case: "Parallel.For.Batched"
   it took 102L ms with GC collects (0, 0, 0), result is: 6.666666168e+11
```

`TailRecursion` and `Fold.Sequential` have similar performance.

`Array.Sequential` does worse because the job is split on two operations `map` and `fold`. In addition we get GC pressure because it allocates an extra array.

`Array.Parallel` is the same as `Array.Sequential` but uses `Array.Parallel.map` over `Array.map`. Here we see there's an overhead of starting many small parallel compuations as small input sizes generate more parallel computations and this takes significant more performance. In addition, the performance is poor even if we use multiple cores. This is because the compuation per element is very small and any benefit of spreading the job over several cores is consumed by the overhead of managing the distribution. When comparing the single thread performance of 390ms with the parallel performance of 990ms one might be suprised that it is 3x worse but in reality it's 12x worse as all 4 cores are used to produce the answer 3x slower.

`Parallel.For` does better as it allows the parallel computation to take place without allocating a new array and the internal overhead is likely lower. Here we manage to gain performance for larger sizes but still lags behind the sequential algorithms for smaller sizes because of the overhead of starting parallel computations.

`Parallel.For.Batched` tries to reduce the overhead by increasing the cost of the individual computations by folding several array values in each parallel computation. Essentially a combination of the `TailRecursion` algorithm and `Parallel.For`. Thanks to this we manage to hit an efficiency of 95% for larger sizes which can be consider decent.

For a simple computation like this AVX could be used as well leading to a potential speedup of around 16X, the cost is that the code will get even hairier.

With a batched parallel for we reached 95% of expected performance speedup.

The point of this is that it's important to continuously measure performance of your parallel algorithms and compare them against trivial sequential implementations.